# Sentence correction (vote, voted)

Tags: grammaticality

How to say:

> Comment was already voted by you

In this sentence I mean that someone made some choice about a comment and I want to tell him about it. Please help me to make my sentence correct and explain to me the correct grammar being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is something like

> The comment was voted on by you.

or

> You already voted on the comment.

or the simpler

> You voted on the comment.

Comment: thank you! But I did not understand why I need "voted on the comment", but not "voted the comment")))) http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23910/vote-or-vote-on

Comment: @Edward83: We use the preposition "on" with *voted* in English. You can also use other prepositions in post-position, such as "You already voted for [or against] the comment" or "The comment was voted down [or up]". My suggestion was the closest to what it looked like you were trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to specify the vote (either 'yes' or 'no', for example) then no preposition would be necessary:

*He voted yes.* -or- *He voted yes on the comment.*

This shows that the subject of the vote (the comment) is voted **on** while the result of the vote does not need the preposition.