# "vote" vs. "vote on"

Tags: differences, verbs, prepositions

Please tell me, what is the difference between

> vote

and

> vote on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Vote" does not usually take a direct object, except in the comparatively rare case where the object is a word or phrase which your vote may be taken to express; so you can "vote 'Yes'" or "vote 'Reopen nominations'".

Normally it takes a indirect object of either of two types:

- vote **for** an option ("I voted for Jones");
- vote **on** a question ("I voted on the motion to close");

You can also vote **in** a poll or election, but I would not count that as an indirect object, but as an adjunct.

There is a more complicated construction which may be analysed in different ways: "They voted him into office". This might regarded as taking "him" as a direct object; but it is impossible without the complement "into office".

Comment: +1 nice answer. Of course there's also "vote against" in addition to "for", and "into office" could be replaced with "out (of office)", "down", "the person with the most ridiculous hairstyle in the room" and so on :-)